# Microsoft Active Directory authentication Single tenant "Live.com"

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I have implemented AD authentication where I have passed Client Id, redirectUri and Tenant as "Common". Since I have used Tenant as "Common" users from live.com, outlook.com, microsoft.com and school and office are allowed. I want it to be restricted to only Live.com users.

```cs
public class Startup
{
    // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
    string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

    // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in.
    string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

    // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
    static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

    // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Azure Active Directory v2 endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0)
    string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0" ;

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(

        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44368/Claims/Register",
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenIdProfile,
            // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.IdToken,
            // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
            // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
            // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter 
            TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters() { ValidateIssuer = false },

            // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = (c) => {
                    var code = c.Code;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        }
    );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Azure AD's v2.0 endpoint docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints):

Once registered, the app communicates with Azure AD by sending requests to the v2.0 endpoint:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Where the `{tenant}` can take one of four different values:

- `common` - Allows users with both personal Microsoft accounts and work/school accounts from Azure Active Directory to sign into the application.
- `organizations` - Allows only users with work/school accounts from Azure Active Directory to sign into the application
- **`consumers` - Allows only users with personal Microsoft accounts (MSA) to sign into the application.**
- `8eaef023-2b34-4da1-9baa-8bc8c9d6a490` or `contoso.onmicrosoft.com` -
  Allows only users with work/school accounts from a particular Azure Active Directory tenant to sign into the application. Either the friendly domain name of the Azure AD tenant or the tenant's guid identifier can be used.

**If you want to limit further down to the consumer domain, (@live.com vs @outlook.com) you'll need to implement that yourself at the application level looking at the `email` claim.** Note that generally this level of filtering doesn't make much sense as there is no functional/practial difference between live.com accounts and outlook.com accounts, they just have a different vanity domain.

Comment: Great answer, to add one more way to restrict access to your app if it's calling your own web API.  Your web API can look in the `iss` claim inside the token issued. Microsoft account users will have a unique tenant id  present here that your backend could validate and restrict access to. Checkout the [Azure AD v2.0 token reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens) for help on the token claim. For the list of sample, checkout the [Azure AD v2.0 landing page](https://aka.ms/aadv2).

Comment: Great that what I wanted.Can i use this AAD endpoint V2 for API authentication.